Show trend for a calculation on a bar chart
I have a view that shows an outstanding balance based on the selected year-month value in the parameter.
The logic for the outstanding balance is as follows.
Amount of all invoices till the selected date in the parameter.
Amount of all invoices that have null c date
Exclude all invoices that have a c date less than or equal to the month selected in the parameter
This gives an amount that is outstanding amount. I need to show this amount on a bar chart such as:
If I select 2024-3 then it should show amounts as per the above calculation till 2024-3 from the start of the date. Here is the expected result.
Totals as per the formula

As per march 2024-3

Chart as per 2024-2

as per Feb-2
The attached worksheet is my initial try.
Please refer to this link for an example workbook.
Workbook

See this documentation on trendlines from Tableau.
